# Security of passwords in bash subcommands

Tags: mysql, bash, security, passwords

I've heard that directly inputting your password on the command line is a bad idea, because anyone could see the "secret" in

```
mysql -u root -psecret
```

by browsing `history`.

I have a password for my MySQL database stored in a text file with limited read permissions, and was wondering if it is safe to access it in the following way:

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat ~/.mysql_pass)
```

Browsing `history`, I see the command printed, not the literal value. So it seems like it's working the way I want it to.

I'm sure there are better ways of handling passwords, I would just like to know whether or not this one is leaving my password completely out in the open.

Comment: You can also add a space before your command, this way `history` won't store it. http://superuser.com/a/324881/204979

Comment: @fedorqui Worth noting that this only works if the `$HISTCONTROL` environment variable has the `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` flag.

Comment: The command line can also be seen via the `ps` command, independent of any shell history mechanisms, or which shell is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've suggested using the following:

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat ~/.mysql_pass)
```

However, the subcommand will be expanded before mysql is executed and so even if this isn't available in the command history, it's entirely possible for someone to view the process list just after invocation and see your password.

I think a better approach is to use a [mysql client options file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) and have the `mysql` command read the password from the options file.

Comment: Actually, in the specific case of MySQL, it hides the password - viewing the process list will show "-pxxxxx" or something similar. But in general, you're correct.

Comment: Right, I was just about to say that it showed `-px` in my case. Is it ok to assume that it's safe with MySQL?

Comment: @chrisf It depends how paranoid you are about security.  The mysql binary itself rewrites its command for the ps list, so there is actually a tiny window of time where the password *could* be seen in the process list.  This is why I mentioned in the answer that it's possible to view the password 'just after invocation'.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `mysql -u root -p` and you'll get a prompt to enter your password and it won't be stored in the history.

Comment: True, but I'm trying for more of a hands-off approach (so I can execute queries from the command line without interruption).